# What is using memory in between 2 while iterations?

Tags: java, memory, while-loop, garbage-collection

I created a function just to test the GC and see the memory usage. The results are very strange.

The memory analyzing class:

```
public class MemoryAnalizer {

private static NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
private static DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) nf;
static long heapSize;
static long heapMaxSize;
static long heapFreeSize;
static long used;

public static void analize()
{
    heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    used = heapSize - heapFreeSize;

    System.out.println("MemoryAnalitics: [ Used: " + df.format(used / 1000) + " Free: " + df.format(heapFreeSize / 1000) + " HeapSize: " + df.format(heapSize / 1000) + " | Max HeapSize: " + df.format(heapMaxSize / 1000) + " (KBs)]");
}
}
```

The Main function that calls the memory analizing before and after the GC call:

```
private static MemoryAnalizer memory = new MemoryAnalizer();

public static void main(String argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println();
        memory.analize();
        System.gc();
        memory.analize();
    }
}
```

The resulting prints show the following results:

```
MemoryAnalitics: [ Used: 977 Free: 124.852 HeapSize: 125.829 | Max HeapSize: 1.860.698 (KBs)]
MemoryAnalitics: [ Used: 305 Free: 125.523 HeapSize: 125.829 | Max HeapSize: 1.860.698 (KBs)]

MemoryAnalitics: [ Used: 977 Free: 124.852 HeapSize: 125.829 | Max HeapSize: 1.860.698 (KBs)]
MemoryAnalitics: [ Used: 305 Free: 125.523 HeapSize: 125.829 | Max HeapSize: 1.860.698 (KBs)]

MemoryAnalitics: [ Used: 977 Free: 124.852 HeapSize: 125.829 | Max HeapSize: 1.860.698 (KBs)]
MemoryAnalitics: [ Used: 305 Free: 125.523 HeapSize: 125.829 | Max HeapSize: 1.860.698 (KBs)]
```

What can explain the increase of 600 KBs of memory between each while loop?

Comment: Note that `System.gc();` is just a hint to the runtime, i.e. it might choose not to do anything or not to collect everything that you'd deem elligible. Besides that, access to the `System.out` printstream will use some memory even it's just a newline character you're printing.

Comment: I reproduced this. Interesting thing: without System.gc call this effect dissapears. I'd like to see the answer too

Comment: Your test is far too naive and simple to draw conclusions from. Your memory analyzer is just not good enough. You'd need to look into [Instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) for precise results.

Also, it's written analyze, not analize.

Comment: I would say that the used memory difference between each call comes from all the unreferenced variables that were collected after calling all that functions to retrive the memory stats. However, this is just a guess. @Kayaman suggestion should point you to the right answer.

Comment: I'd have to guess but I'd say it's the objects that are needed by your `analize()` call. Add another `System.gc()` at the end of the loop and you'll  see almost no difference in memory usage.

Comment: "Note that System.gc(); is just a hint to the runtime" exactly, that's what i wanted initially to test\see just for curiosity. I was therefore expecting the Used values to fluctuate depending on the GC running or not as it pleases, but it actually runs, aparently. "Your memory analyzer is just not good enough" true, but for this test purpouse, the objective is to see the diferences, therefore for this badly calculated value it should a) keep the same bad value, or b) just jump around. But it looks too paterned for something like that, hinting that there is something in there doing this.